# Getting context path in a tag library

Tags: spring-mvc

is it possible to get the context path in a class extending SimpleTagSupport?
or is it actually necessary to pass it as a parameter to my tag?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
ServletContext servletContext = ((PageContext) getJspContext()).getServletContext();

String appContext = servletContext.getContextPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you. In jsp view files

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:set var="ctx" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
```